# Custom radio modules/frequencies for ELRS

Tags: rf, remote-control, uav

I'm trying to develop a custom RX/TX for UAV piloting on a non-standard frequency.

I tried decoding CRSF from the remote control, connecting to the S.Port etc., but without much luck.

I figured out it should be easier to use an ELRS and ESP32 + radio module. I have a bunch of radio modules from E-BYTE that are not supported by ELRS natively.

Does anyone have any experience with ELRS modifications? Should I be good if I develop a software driver for my radio modules, or do custom frequencies require more modifications to the ELRS firmware?

Comment: which frequency are you thinking of using? ... can you do so legally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking about literally any frequency. I'm allowed to do so legally, so this aspect is not an issue